# git rebase after branch has been merged into master

Tags: git

Say I have a master branch and a feature branch called FA1 that is branched off master and I have another feature branch called FA2 that is branched off FA1.

When I'm working on FA2 and I want to bring changes from FA1, I do: `git rebase -i FA1`.

However, at some point FA1 gets merged into master and I want to change FA2 to be based off master now, it no longer makes sense that is branched off FA1.

What is the proper approach to change the target branch of FA2 to be master OR in other words, for FA2 to be up to date with master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make FA2 derive directly from master :

```
 git checkout FA2
 git rebase FA1 FA2
 git rebase --onto master FA1 FA2
```

see the [rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

Comment: Note that if you omit FA2 it default to current head so  `git rebase --onto master FA1` does the same thing

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master
```

Background: Git does not store anywhere which branch you rebased onto in the past, so it does not know you rebased onto `FA1` previously, and as such there is noting special to do when you want to switch the base to rebase into, expcept, well to specify that new base to `rebase`.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] it no longer makes sense that is branched off FA1 [...]

This is not quite true. Whether branch `FA2` still exists or not, `FA1` stays branched off *the same commit*.

If you then need to bring into `FA2` recent commits merged into `master`, yes, you can indeed rebase `FA2` on `master` as you did before with `FA1`.